# i tried to call servlet class by jquery ajax but i failed,and got this error

Tags: ajax, servlets

I tried to call servlet class by jquery ajax but i failed,and got this error. what should I do to fix it ??

```
POST http//localhost:8080/AkiDar/CpanelServlet 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
send jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.js:7968
sendToServlet
onclick
```

and this is jQuery Ajax

```
var mainDesID=document.staticForm.mainDesID.value;

var firstName=document.staticForm.firstName.value;

var lastName=document.staticForm.lastName.value;
var address=document.staticForm.address.value;
var xpoint=document.staticForm.xpoint.value;
var ypoint=document.staticForm.ypoint.value;

var xstreet=document.staticForm.xstreet.value;

var ystreet=document.staticForm.ystreet.value;
var phoneNumber=document.staticForm.phoneNumber.value;
var email=document.staticForm.email.value;
var url=document.staticForm.url.value;
var description=document.staticForm.description.value;
var details=document.staticForm.details.value;
var type=document.staticForm.type.value;



var json= {
    'mainDesID':mainDesID , 
    'firstName':firstName,
    'lastName':lastName,
    'xpoint':xpoint,
    'ypoint':ypoint,
    'xstreet':xstreet,
    'ystreet':ystreet,
    'address':address,
    'phoneNumber':phoneNumber,
    'email':email,
    'url':url,
    'description':description,
    'type':type,
    'specialize':'dddd',
    'details':details
};



console.log(json);
$.ajax({
    url:"/AkiDar/CpanelServlet",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){

    },
    data:json

});
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
        version="2.5">   
        <display-name>AkiDar</display-name>  
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>   
        </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared any servlet in your web.xml file, and you haven't mapped any URL either. So obviously, your servlet is unavailable.

Here's [a tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html) explaining how to declare and map a servlet. You need the following in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>someServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fully.qualified.name.of.ServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>someServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CpanelServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```